# Ubuntu stuck at startup after /var/log/ files caused "disk space" error

Tags: logrotate

I started to work with pcie card on my Ubuntu pc. I have noticed that during operation, log files size at /var/log/ is increasing rapidly, especially syslog file (reached 36GB). it filled up with thousands lines of pcie read/write kernel massages.
As consequences, free disk space is now empty, and I can't save anything or open the browser.

I tried different solutions including deleting zipped and *.log.1 files, logrotating the file, unsuccessfully. The only way I was able to get out of this mess was to restart the pc, until now.

How to configure the log files not to save pci massages?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make a backup of your grub configuration file, in a terminal run:

```
   sudo cp /etc/default/grub ~/grub.back
```

Edit the file:

```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that has:

```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= “quiet splash”
```

Add pci=noaer to this line. AER stands for Advanced Error Reporting, and "noaer" tells the kernel not to use or log Advanced Error Reporting, so it looks like this:

```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
```

Save the file: Ctrl + O

Close Nano: Ctrl + X

Update grub:

```
   sudo update-grub
```

Restart Ubuntu